# Javascript function defined in view.js not reachable from save.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to develop a custom gutenberg block.
I have a form in save.js:

```
export default function save() {
return (
    <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
</div>);}
```

File view.js is defined in block.json ("viewScript":  "file:./view.js",)

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(event.target);
...
};
```

But when the block renders, it fails.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSubmit is not defined
```

Its all nice if i use "traditional" javascript (e.g. jQuery, console.log), so enqueueing is not the problem.
I am pretty new with "modern" javascript (React, Angular...) and the question is surely pretty dumb, but i am looking for a proper way to coding and not only looking for a functional solution.